# Почему подросток пишется через О, ведь перед СТ пишется А?

Tags: орфография

Почему?

Comment: Потому что под ударением. )))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В нашем случае гласная ударная. А под ударением мы пишем, что слышим.

Answer (score 4):

Правило о правописании корней с чередованием относится к безударным гласным. Но здесь стоит сказать не столько о слове "подросток", сколько о слове "подростковый". Вот здесь действительно в безударном положении пишется О, хотя перед СТ. Можно, конечно, сослаться на "подрОсток", но ведь говорим же, что корни с чередованием ударением проверять нельзя (зАрево, зОрька). Значит, действительно стоит внести слово "подростковый" в список исключений.

Comment: Вообще-то, я всегда знал, что слово "подрОстковый" произносится с ударением на 2-м слоге

Comment: Тут действительно ударение смещается. Виктор прав, "ПодросткОвый" - это торгаши занесли. "Подростковый фасончик".  
  
А вообще "список исключений" надо просто переформулировать. Иначе вопросов, пожобных рассматриваемому не избежать.

Comment: Посмотрела в словари. Уже у Аванесова (80-е годы) подросткОвый - допустимо. Слушая лекции по психологии, по педагогике   в те же 80-е от лекторов слышала только подросткОвый возраст. С торгашами у меня никак не связывается. ПодрОстковый не слышала никогда.

Comment: Я  тоже  никогда  не  слышал  -  подрОстковый.

Comment: >Уже у Аванесова (80-е годы) подросткОвый - допустимо. 

Так занесли-то в пятидесятые-шестидесятые. Под "торгашами" я имел в виду ненавязчивый советский сервис и легкую промышленность. 
Сейчас, понятно, подрОстковый устаревает, если не "уже устарело". 
Но оно существовало как единственно нормативное, Виктор вполне мог застать те времена. Он же не утверждает, что сейчас надо произносить именно так.

Answer (score 1):

Очередной пример того, что вопросы, начинающиеся с "почему" обычно не имеют правильного ответа. 
Можно было бы еще попытаться ответить на вопрос, почему при формулировке "детской" запоминалки с чередованием рос/раст/ращ не позаботились о списке всех исключений...
Ну понятно, что о словах с гласной под ударением традиционно забывают. Но хотя бы упомянуть о подобных случаях вполне можно...

**//------------------------**
Я еще забыл сказать, что отсылка на ударность гласной тоже не закрывает вопроса. Надо еще упомянуть, что производные от "рост" в значении "длина одежды" всегда с О: ростОвой, ростОвка и проч. Хотя "ростовой" годится для обоих значений... Чума, короче, с этим правилом.

Comment: А что за детская "запоминалка"? Вообще в школе сейчас не только "росток" и "отрасль", как когда-то. Но и Ростов, и Ростислав и т.п.

Comment: Так она и есть детская: "раст, ращ через А, рос - через О. исключения: росток, отрасль, ростовщик и производные" И хоть бы кто упомянул что это только про безударные. Собственные - это отдельная песня.     
Ну ладно, "отросток", допустим, производное от "росток", а "вырост", "прирост"? А то, что само слово "рост" через О пишется?

Comment: Ваше "и хоть бы кто" не совсем верно. В школьных учебниках сначала говорится о том, что безударные гласные бывают проверяемыми, непроверяемыми и чередующимися. Учителя это подчеркивают обязательно.

Comment: Простите, но, во-первых, этот факт существования непроверяемых и проверяемых гласных если и имеет отношение к конкретным корневым чередованиям, то весьма косвенное, а во-вторых, правило формулируется - и зазубривается(!) - без всякого упоминания об *ударных* гласных. Аналогичный, кстати, случай имеет место, например, в отношении списка глаголов-исключений огромное число глаголов относятся "не к тому" спряжению, но в списках они не упоминаются, т.к. считается, что они не вызывают вопросов в силу ударенности гласной в суффиксе.

Comment: Я вообще против правил, которые надо именно зазубрить (а не понять), а данное правило именно такое, на зубрёжку, ибо понять это нельзя, только запомнить.  
Но уж если зубрить, то такие формулировки, которые не допускают двусмысленностей. Как в воинских уставах. 
Кстати, а как быть глухим от рождения детям? Иностранцам? Они не знают, куда падает ударение, они хотят видеть *исчерпывающую* формулировку.

Comment: Я Вам говорю, что в школе подчеркивается, что правило относится к безударным гласным. Почему не верите? Потому что вопрос такой задали? Так незнание конкретного человека еще не значит, что этому не учат.

Comment: @tmp, до абсурда - не доводИте! :-) Человек либо *слышит* слово (и тогда *знает*, куда падает ударение), либо видит письменное слово - и тогда он знает, как его писать - зачем ему *исчерпывающая формулировка*?

Comment: stopkran, без комментариев.

 
>Я Вам говорю, что в школе подчеркивается, что правило относится к безударным гласным  

Вы этого раньше не говорили. Т.е. не вообще - а *именно этого*. Ну хорошо, допустим я Вас не понял. Приведите тогда, пожалуйста, полную формулировку по школьному учебнику. С учетом этой оговорки. Я к сожалению не имею возможности посмотреть сам. А в сети сколько ни смотрю - никде это не подчеркивается.

Answer (score 1):

Я что-то не поняла, почему удалён мой ответ (а он был первым) и мой комментарий, где я как раз писала про безударные гласные.   Честно говоря, очень неприятная неожиданность.(((

Comment: Повторите. Я думаю, тут не было злонамеренности. Бывает такое. Видимо из-за некорректной работы базы данных.

Answer (score 0):

В русском языке есть понятие сильная и слабая позиция.Сильная позиция для гласных- под ударением пишем то, что слышим: подрОсток, а прилагательное подростковый образовано от существительного подросток. Точно так же , как и в словах зАрево, зОрька, а в безударном положении только А: заря; 
ещё пример: клАняться, поклОн, а в безударном положении -только О:поклОнение